# Data not loading on the first load changing perspective (Hybris)

Tags: widget, load, sap-commerce-cloud, zk, backoffice

I've made a custom backoffice widget which I can access by clicking the new Order Cockpit item added in the option perspectives tree. This will show different graphs with data in it.
But for some reason the data doesn't load on the first load, but when refreshing the page it works perfect. Is there any way to configure to refresh or re-init the widget when clicking the Order Cockpit item in the option tree?

[image: option tree]

[image: order cockpit widget]

widgetdefinition.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<!--
 Copyright (c) 2020 SAP SE or an SAP affiliate company. All rights reserved
-->
<widget-definition xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                   xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://www.hybris.com/schema/cockpitng/widget-definition.xsd"
                   id="org.training.widgets.customGraphWidget">
    <name>customGraph Sample Widget</name>
    <description>customGraph Sample Widget</description>
    <defaultTitle>customGraph Sample Widget</defaultTitle>
    <author>DucVan</author>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <view src="customGraphWidget.zul" />
    <keywords>
        <keyword>graphbackoffice</keyword>
    </keywords>
    <controller class="org.training.widgets.customGraphController" />
</widget-definition>
```

widgetController

```java
package org.training.widgets;


import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.hybris.cockpitng.core.model.WidgetModel;


import org.training.services.customGraphService;
import org.zkoss.zk.ui.Component;
import org.zkoss.zk.ui.select.annotation.WireVariable;

import com.hybris.cockpitng.util.DefaultWidgetController;

import java.util.List;


public class customGraphController extends DefaultWidgetController {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7954736389190109887L;

    @WireVariable
    private transient customGraphService customGraphService;


    @Override
    public void preInitialize(Component comp) {
        super.preInitialize(comp);


        WidgetModel model = getWidgetInstanceManager().getModel();
        model.put("orders", convertAllOrderModelsToJSON());


    }

    private Object convertAllOrderModelsToJSON() {
        //get all the models
        List list = customGraphService.getAllOrdersModels();
        //convert models to JSON
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
        String json = gson.toJson(list);
        return json;

    }

}
```

zul page

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>


<widget xmlns="http://www.zkoss.org/2005/zul"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:h="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
        xmlns:w="http://www.zkoss.org/2005/zk/client"
        xmlns:zk="http://www.zkoss.org/2005/zk"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.zkoss.org/2005/zul http://www.hybris.com/schema/cockpitng/zul/zul.xsd"
        height="100%">

    <html>
        <h:head>

            <h:script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.6.0/chart.js"
                      integrity="sha512-CWVDkca3f3uAWgDNVzW+W4XJbiC3CH84P2aWZXj+DqI6PNbTzXbl1dIzEHeNJpYSn4B6U8miSZb/hCws7FnUZA=="
                      crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" defer="true"/>
            <h:script>const orders = [${widgetModel.orders}][0];</h:script>
            <h:script defer="true" src="widgetClasspathResource/widgets/customGraphWidget/graphConfiguration.js?v=1"/>
        </h:head>


        <h:body>
            <h:div style="height: 100%; width: 80%; margin: auto; overflow: hidden;">


                <h:div style="background-color: white;height:35%;margin: 40px auto auto
                            ;padding:20px;border: 2px solid #d7dee5">
                    <h:canvas id="lineChart1"></h:canvas>
                </h:div>


                <h:div style="background-color: white;width: 30%;height:35%;margin: 30px auto auto 0px
            ;padding:20px;border: 2px solid #d7dee5;float: left">
                    <h:canvas id="pieChart1"></h:canvas>
                </h:div>

                <h:div style="background-color: white;width: 60%;height:35%;margin: 30px 0px auto auto
            ;padding:20px;border: 2px solid #d7dee5">
                    <h:canvas id="barChart1"></h:canvas>
                </h:div>


            </h:div>


        </h:body>

    </html>


</widget>
```

Comment: Please post the code you used, the widgets involved, and your version of hybris.

Comment: I've added the code

Comment: Using defer is not recommended if you import internal script. But I don't think it's the main issue. You should probably check in your browser when the JS is loaded and if it execute correctly. When you load the page the first time the script is not loaded and you only see your div. The second time, the script is probably taken from cache and is executed correctly.

Comment: yes exaclty, the first time you load the site it's standard on the admin cockpit. And it says fails to load the graphs because it's currently on the wrong page it doesn't find the document element. Is there any way to only  load the widget when navigating to it?

Comment: I guess you have to choice. 1) Create an event in your JS file when your div is ready to load the graph. 2) Fix the widget layout, I usually don't create a full HTML page in the widget. You should check the widget MetadataViewerModal to see what I mean.